# User constantly adds the wrong tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed one user constantly adding the wrong tag to his own questions. These questions are [yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii2) related only, but he also adds the [yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii) tag. Yii 2 is completely different than the first version.

Even if I remove this tag, he returns it back.

What should we do in this case?

Examples:

- [Setting aliases in Yii2 within the app config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797051/setting-aliases-in-yii2-within-the-app-config-file)
- [Creating a dropdown list in Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588624/creating-a-dropdown-list-in-yii2)

Maybe he doesn't understand that this tag is only for first version of the framework, and we should explain it in comments?

**Update:**

Please stop downvoting this question without understanding the situation.

I was answering and moderating the questions with `yii2` tag only since the first days I registered on Stack Overflow.

Very few amount of them have `yii` tag combined with `yii2`, in particular I can remember it from user I mentioned.

I also saw that other users deleting `yii` tag for `yii2` questions, so I thought this is the right behavior.

If the `yii` tag should be used as general, what tag should be used for specifying version one?

It simply does not exist at this moment.

Also description of tag was changed right after I posted this question. At the moment I was writing it was:

> This tag is for versions 1.1x

Anyways I think I raised the actual problem, it turns that it's not related with this user specifically, but with `yii` tags ambiguity.

If it's generic tag, please add tag for version 1.

Sad to see that when you want to be helpful and make site better you get downvotes.

Should I create another question about creating tag for version one of Yii?

I saw now after changing description of tag some users start to add it together with `yii2`.

Also what should we do with `yii` version one questions after adding generic tag?

Comment: If you find yourself in an edit war, just flag it.

Comment: What reason I should set when adding the flag?

Comment: That you have come into an edit war. Explain the reason why the tag should be removed and then leave it.

Comment: You should mention that the OP is rolling back those tag edits on their own question. Why do you think you're right even if the OP claims that the yii tag doesn't explicitely state it is for version 1 only? You could leave a comment for the OP to find out their point-of-view instead of taking it to the moderator.

Comment: Added specification about own answers. The tag info actually says: "This tag is for versions 1.1x". And also from personal experience - I answering yii2 tag questions only, mix of two is rarely meets and always corrected to specify exact version.

Comment: OK, I left a comment for the OP pointing out that their question is being discussed here.

Comment: Is the difference between [tag:yii] and [tag:yii2], as mentioned in the tag description for the latter, large enough to be worth mentioning explicitly in [tag:yii] itself? I.e., something like "Questions regarding Yii2 must not use this tag because (...of those changes...)".

Comment: Perhaps all (or most) yii-questions should be tagged yii1, at least if they touch on anything which changed... though that's 12K questions, probably too much work, at least without sacrificing all accuracy.

Comment: A mod could rename the tag to remove this confusion, but of course the community needs to first agree on a new name.

Comment: With 10 times more followers on the generic version vs the more specific one, if I was OP I would tag it that way too for better potential answer exposure

Comment: I don't see *why* [tag:yii] should be used only for the 1.x version... The [tag:java] tag doesn't refer only to java 1.x, nor does the [tag:python] refer only to python 1.x, nor anything else. The tag for a given language/framework should be *generic*, and, if needed, version specific tags should be *added*.

Comment: I agree; the confusion lies with the tag, not the OP.

Comment: If the yii tag is only for version 1, why does the yii tag's info page contain all sorts of info about version 2? That's been there for several months longer than the excerpt's mention of being specific to version 1.

Comment: The tag excerpt now mentions that it's just for 1.x. Hopefully someone can update the [tag:yii] and [tag:yii2] wikis to match the new meanings.

Comment: Why was the tag changed just to mean 1.x when most users are using it as a general tag?! I agree with @Bakuriu it doesn't make any sense. This is just ruining the tag for one person's preference. Or should we do the same for Java, Zend, and Python too?! Leave the yii generic tag for all versions and add a yii1 along with yii2.

Comment: I would: 1) develop versions for tags, then prevent users to use more than one version (yii or yii2); and 2) show more info and awareness on tags when users focus the input for tags (cause regular users think the more tags they write, the better).

Comment: I agree with @Bakuriu. Common practice on SO (in my experience at least) is that tags without version numbers should be generic. People who are interested in the Yii framework can then subscribe to that tag. To indicate whether or not you're using Yii 1.x or Yii 2.x should be an additional tag.

Comment: We use two tags on Delphi questions.  The tag Delphi and then the version, Delphi-XE, for example.  The prolific answerers (is that a word?) of Delphi questions are pretty quick to request that the OP include the additional version tag because it can make a big difference on the content of the answer.  This seems like a similar use case.

Comment: I think that this issue affects the planet deeply.

Comment: I am the OP. I was actually going to create a meta post about this myself as the OP of this meta post kept removing my `Yii` tag. The reason I kept adding it was because of the exact reason that @Bakuriu says. Why should the `Yii` tag be specific to Yii 1 only? People seem to be able to use generic tags such as `WordPress`, `PHP` etc for general use or should they only be restricted to version 1 of those releases? I don't think that would be a good idea. That's my POV anyway.

Comment: @Brett: I dislike questions with both the specific and the generic tag. Either the question is specific about a very version, then this tag should be used. Otherwise the generic one. In general I don't see a reason for duplucate tagging.

Comment: @usr1234567: If there were good tag-hierarchies, that would be laudable. There aren't though...

Answer (score 37):

From the description of [yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii) tag:

> Yii is a high-performance, MVC architecture based, open source PHP framework 
>   best for developing Web 2.0 applications. This tag is a general tag
>   used for both Yii and Yii2.

So in that case, the [yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii) tag is appropriate for questions about Yii2.

If you think the description and usage of the [yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii) tag is invalid, start the meta discussion. But according to the current state, that user has right, not you, because he acts according to wiki excerpt, not you.

Comment: While your answer is correct, and I agree that this tag should indeed be a general tag, I would like to point out the excerpt was changed after this meta post to say it is general use. Yesterday when I looked, it did indeed say it was only for Yii version 1.x. (That said, the excerpt was changed sometime in January to say it was for 1.x only, so it does seem to have been intended originally as a general tag.) Basically, just pointing out in your last paragraph, yesterday the OP here was the one acting according to the excerpt, not the SO OP.

Comment: The change in the excerpt says: "This tag is a general tag. Most questions that have been tagged include yii2, and not just yii1. Please make a separate tag for yii1 if needed, to avoid confusion." http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7217654

Comment: First of all, description was changed right after I wrote this post. And please check how tags are filled for other questions for yii and yii2.

Comment: Removed the second sentence from the excerpt as it is pure fluff, until there's yii3, at which time it will simply be wrong.

Comment: ...and people are fiddling with the excerpt again and trying to tell people it's only for Yii1 use.

Comment: This tag has been edited once again, gawd.

Answer (score 1):

IMO everything that is historically tagged with [yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii) belongs to version 1. Since Yii 2 is so different compared to the first version, nobody wants to see those questions that belong to version 1. For a Yii 2 developer it makes no sense to see them. And vice versa. Version 1 and 2 have very little in common.

If stackoverflow would have exist some years before we could have the same effect with VB: First there was VB6 and than VB.NET. Before VB.NET most people would probably have tagged their questions just with VB. Nobody was prepared that there will be VB.NET. But than it was there. From then it made no sense to use the VB tag anymore. Besause VB and VB.NET have also not much in common (just syntactically).

Another comparison: most movies have a normal title. A sequel often has the same title with '2' appended (sometimes also 33 1/3 ;-) ). There are also other movies that have a '1' in the title when it is already known that there will be a sequel. But it is generally accepted (in written form) that if there is no number at the end of the movie title it refers to the first part.

Finally, I would say [yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii) should stand for Yii 1 and [yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii2) for Yii 2. Or [yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii)  should be renamed to [yii1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii1).

It is an exception and cannot be compared to versioning e.g. in Java.