# Series of edits removing [yii] tag from [yii2] questions

Tags: discussion, tags

I've come across [a few edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3041129/size?tab=activity&sort=revisions) removing [yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii) from questions tagged [yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii) and [yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii2).

The tag info currently says `yii` "is a general tag used for both Yii and Yii2."

[I found this old discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287174/user-constantly-adds-the-wrong-tag) where the tag at one point was changed from a general tag to specifically refer to `yii1`, but it was restored back to a general tag at the time of the discussion.

That question's consensus seems to be that the tag should be general, and I think these edits to remove the general tag should, in retrospect, have been rejected.

*I made the mistake of approving some of the recent edits, before I took the time to check for a meta discussion about the tag.*

I think the correct action is to restore the `yii` tag, but I wanted to double-check with the community before reverting the edit.

Comment: *sigh* and there are users still doing this...

Answer (score -3):

I do not agree on using yii for yii 1.0 and yii2 questions because these two versions are significantly different and users should be able to watch specific versions..

Comment: Can't you accomplish that now by using the **Ignored tags** feature to ignore the specific version you're not interested in?

Comment: Then make a FR for having them all retagged to Yii1.