# Is [SDL] only for SDL 1.x?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

There're [sdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl) and [sdl-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl-2). SDL 1.x and SDL 2.x are different APIs. Should a question that asks something about SDL2 include [sdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl) too, or only the [sdl-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdl-2)?

Answer (score 2):

That reminds me of [yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii), and the drama there:
[User constantly adds the wrong tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287174)
[Series of edits removing [yii] tag from [yii2] questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305736)

The conclusion was, either it's a generic tag for all version, or the tag-name is wrong and one should start a meta-post to convince people the mods should retag them all to a version-tag and kill the non-versioned one because the differences are too great, probably including blacklisting.

For some reason, that never happened there, and I don't expect that to happen here.